# .fetch() on collection gives TypeError

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min.js"></script> 
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.0.0/backbone-min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
<script>
  var mod=Backbone.Model.extend({});
  var col=Backbone.Collection.extend({model:mod, url: 'test.php'});
  col.fetch();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If run this primitive code in Firefox, Firebug gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: col.fetch is not a function
col.fetch();
```

Why is that? I can't see no error or typo... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have few mistakes in your code:

1. You need to specify model and collection:

   ```
   var Mod = Backbone.Model.extend({});
   var Col = Backbone.Collection.extend({model: Mod, url: 'test.php'});
   ```
2. Create instance of collection with specified model:

   ```
   var collectionInstance = new Col({model: new Mod()});
   ```
3. Fetch collection:

   ```
   collectionInstance.fetch();
   ```

For more details, please, see [Backbone docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-models).

Comment: Their `mod` is your `MyModel` so your first point doesn't really apply, there's just some non-standard naming going on. And your second point should say `new MyCollection([ new MyModel ])`, no?

Comment: You could also just create the instance in one go if you wanted for example `var col= new (Backbone.Collection.extend({model:mod, url: 'test.php'}))();`

Comment: Or just `var collectionInstance = new MyCollection;` if you're going to populate it with a `fetch` call.

Comment: Thanks, guys, for your comments, where I can see details about naming standards?

Comment: "classes" are usually LikeThis but instances are likeThis or like_this depending on local conventions. I think not following the conventions is part of the OP's confusion here. I think `var Mod=Backbone.Model.extend({});var Col = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: Mod, url: '...'); var col = new Col; col.fetch()` is probably what they're after.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiar with a Class/Constructor/Prototype vs Instance here is an explanation:

Say we have a forum where every user has some posts. We want to represent the Posts a user has in a Collection called "Posts". Now here's the thing, you can can have multiple users, therefore you will need multiple `instances` of the collection (which is basically an array with some super-cool features that Backbone provides and you specify). We want to create a "blueprint" for how this array works and the cool things it can do (because we don't want to rewrite the functionality for every single array we create). A Class/Constructor/Prototype is that blueprint.

```
//Post is a Model Class/Constructor/Prototype. We can make multiple "instances" of Post. 
var Post = Backbone.Model.extend({
   starPost: function() {
      //contains code to "star" a post 
   },
   pinPost: function(){
      //contains code to "pin" the post
   },
   //some other cool functions to do cool things to a post
});

//Posts is the Collection Class/Constructor/Prototype. We can make multiple "instances" of Posts for each User.
var Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: function() {
     return '/api/posts/' + this.options.userID
  },
  model: Post,
  findStarredPosts: function(){
    //has code to return all Post models that are "starred"
  },
  findPinnedPosts: function(){
    //has code to return all Post models that are "pinned"
  }
});

//please note that the FIRST ARGUMENT is an empty array (meaning we are starting this collection with no models inside). the SECOND ARGUMENT is the options (which will be saved into the instances `this.options`). `options` is what makes this instance unique when going to the server. You need to write in your `url` function HOW you're going to use what you passed in `options` to communicate with the server
var user1Posts = new Posts([], {
   userID: 123 //this is an option passed in which is specific to this INSTANCE. It will get read by the `url` function and generate an instance of this posts collection Specific to user1
});

var user2Posts = new Posts([], {
   userID: 456 //this is an option passed in which is specific to this INSTANCE. It will get read by the `url` function and generate an instance of this posts collection Specific to user2
});

//this command actually tells Backbone to go our and request user1's posts from the server and put them into the `user1Posts` collection.
user1Posts.fetch();
```

Point being, you NEVER run functions on Constructors/Prototypes/Classes. You only act on their instances. The only thing you can do is create instances of those Constructors/Prototypes/Classes.

I hope this makes some sense. If not I can (and will) clarify.